# Is it possible to evaluate an expression using dynamic objects?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm using the following code to evaluate expressions based on my strongly typed objects:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using E = System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Person { public string Name { get; set; } }

[Test]
public void Evaluate_expression_using_strongly_typed_object()
{
    Person obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<person>("{ 'Name': 'John Smith'}");
    string name = obj.Name;

    var t = obj.GetType();
    var p = E.Expression.Parameter(obj.GetType(), "obj");
    var e = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, "obj.Name = \"John Smith\"");
    Assert.That((bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(obj) == true);
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing using a dynamic object?
ie:

```
[Test]
public void Evaluate_expression_using_dynamic_object()
{
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");
    string name = obj.Name;
    string address = obj.Address.City;

    var t = obj.GetType();
    var p = E.Expression.Parameter(obj.GetType(), "obj");
    var e = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, "obj.Name = \"John Smith\"");
    Assert.That((bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(obj) == true);
}
```

This second block of code does not compile. 
new[] { p }  - Cannot convert from 'dynamic[]' to 'System.Type'

-- Edit --

If I cast the 'dynamic[]' to 'System.Type' then I get the following error.
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 'No property or field 'Name' exists in type 'JObject''

```
var p = E.Expression.Parameter((Type)obj.GetType(), "obj");
```

Comment: "an error", please post the actual error. Also, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Lasse, the error prevents compilation and is "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'dynamic[]' to 'System.Type'"

Comment: Edited by copying my NUnit tests. The strongly typed code works but the dynamic code does not compile.  I think the code is 'Minimal, Complete and Verifiable'. Let me know if you need more. Thanks

Comment: `dynamic` is keyword supported by ***design-time compiler***, it translates all the expressions into `ExpandoObject` and internally handles everything. So I don't think dynamic LINQ supports that.